# Problems with using Specific versions of DLLS

Tags: wpf, windows, dll, chromium, cefsharp

I am having a problem where I am building an WPF managed windows application. This application uses CEF Sharp -a managed library that is basically bindings for the "Chromium Embedded Framework" an unmanaged library. This has a dependancy on the angle project via DLL's - libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll.

The problem I am having is that I am using a another native library which has its versions of the DLL's. These dll's are similar - but definitely different.

The problem I am having is ensuring each of these dependancies use their own version of the library. Currently the chromium and the other library load the gl dll's from the same directory the .exe is in.

What is the best/most efficient way to solve this problem? I have done some reading around - some sources suggest "WinSxS" should work - while others suggest that it only works for separate apps - and not the same process using different versions of DLL's.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically as roadmap:

1. Move all CEF related files into separate directory.
2. Load libcef.dll from this directory (better to consult to cefsharp documentation) or just use LoadLibraryEx before you touch CefSharp.
3. At this moment CEF should load anything from own directory, but this might be needed to recheck.
4. Load your second library. Ensure that it loads angle from own directory.

Depending from result you will be able to decide what to do. For example you might need patch second library to force it load angle using correct path.

ADD: You may want play with SetDllDirectory or other LoadLibrary stuff, but first thing is move CEF binaries to other directory - it designed to work in that case.

Comment: You can add a `CefSharpTargetDir` property to your project, before all the `CefSharp` target files and it should copy all the files to a subfolder, been a long while since I tested this option though. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/67/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.targets#L18